# Unable to Access User Data Using Google Admin SDK Directory API with Service Account

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to access user data using the Google Admin SDK Directory API with a service account. Here's the scenario:

I have a Python script that utilizes the Google Admin SDK Directory API to retrieve user data.
I'm using a service account to authenticate the API requests.
I've followed the steps outlined in the Google documentation to set up domain-wide delegation, and I've granted the necessary permissions to the service account, including the "User Management Admin" role.
When I attempt to retrieve user data for non-admin users, I receive a 403 error with the message "Not Authorized to access this resource/api".
Here's a simplified version of my Python script:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Replace 'path/to/your/service-account-key.json' with the path to your service account key file
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE = 'path/to/your/service-account-key.json'
# Replace 'user@example.com' with the email address you want to check
USER_EMAIL_TO_CHECK = 'user@example.com'

# Load service account credentials
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE,
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'],
)

# Impersonate the user
credentials = credentials.with_subject(USER_EMAIL_TO_CHECK)
# Build the Admin SDK Directory API client
directory_service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)

try:
    # Retrieve user information
    user = directory_service.users().get(userKey=USER_EMAIL_TO_CHECK).execute()
    print(user)
    # If the user exists, print their information
    print(f'User exists in Active Directory: {user["primaryEmail"]}')
except Exception as e:
    # If an exception occurs, the user does not exist
    print(f'User does not exist in Active Directory: {USER_EMAIL_TO_CHECK}')
    print(f'Error: {e}')
```

I've verified that the service account is correctly set up with domain-wide delegation and has the necessary permissions.
I've also ensured that the user I'm trying to impersonate exists in the Active Directory.

Can anyone provide insight into why I'm receiving a 403 error when attempting to access user data for non-admin users using the Google Admin SDK Directory API with a service account, despite having set up domain-wide delegation and granting the necessary permissions?
also I am getting details for the admin email id but getting 403 error for other emails in my workspace

Comment: Which permissions does the user have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With google workspace you need to deligate to a user on the domain.  this is done using create_delegated

```
def build_service_service_account_workspace(credentials, scope, delegated_user):
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        credentials,
        scopes=scope,
    )
    credentials = credentials.create_delegated(delegated_user)
    try:
        return build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - any errors returned.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```

Remember that the service account is only going to have access that the delighted user has.   If the user doesn't have permission to do something it won't be able to sounds like you should be deligating to an admin user

Answer (score 1):

```py
# Impersonate the user
credentials = credentials.with_subject(USER_WITH_ADMIN_ROLE)
```

The USER_WITH_ADMIN_ROLE has to be admin or a delegated admin role to see users.